# How can I validate that an XRP address is valid?

Tags: ripple, xrp-reserve

An address like `rhe8v7GW1jj4qTXsLF9fwFrum9oQD5VXG7` - how do I know if it's valid in the XRP network?

Comment: https://bithomp.com/explorer/

Answer (score 1):

Ripple addresses, like Bitcoin and most other currencies, are [Base58Check encoded](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Base58Check_encoding). As long as an address validates against the base58check algo, it is a valid address on the ripple network.

Do note that it is possible to generate valid addresses without knowing their corresponding private key. You should take steps to ensure you have the private key for an address before sending funds to it.

Comment: it's not true. For istance, valid XRP address r9hEDb4xBGRfBCcX3E4FirDWQBAYtpxC8K is not base58 encoded

Comment: XRP uses a different base58 dictionary from Bitcoin: `rpshnaf39wBUDNEGHJKLM4PQRST7VWXYZ2bcdeCg65jkm8oFqi1tuvAxyz` - The algorithm is still Base58Check.